# Running E2E Tests with Protractor and Angular 4

Tags: angular, protractor

I was trying to run some e2e tests for one of the Angular 4 project that I have!

I have been getting some errors which I could not resolve!

Here is the error message:

```
/usr/local/bin/node /Users/jothi/Books/Angular/ng-book-_The_Complete_Guide_to_Angular_4_-_basic_package/ng-book-code/http/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/plugins/JavaScriptLanguage/helpers/protractor-intellij/lib/protractor-intellij-config.js --intellijOriginalConfigFile=/Users/jothi/Books/Angular/ng-book-_The_Complete_Guide_to_Angular_4_-_basic_package/ng-book-code/http/protractor.conf.js --disableChecks
(node:63426) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[19:38:44] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[19:38:44] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[19:38:44] E/direct - Error code: 135
[19:38:44] E/direct - Error message: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
[19:38:44] E/direct - Error: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
```

Could anyone share with me what the problem actually is and how to solve it?

I'm running it from within WebStorm IDE!

EDIT: Here is my protractor.conf file:

```
// Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
// https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  beforeLaunch: function() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
  },
  onPrepare() {
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
};
```

Comment: You want to run them in browser or in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to download chromedriver with webdriver-manager before running tests:

```
"scripts": {
    "pretest": "webdriver-manager update",
    "test": "protractor protractor.conf.js",
},
```

Then run with terminal command in folder where your package.json file is -

`npm test`

this will install ChromeDriver and run tests

Answer (score 0):

you `directConnect: true,` in your protractor.cong.js to directly run your test cases rather using a webdriver!

```
 ....
 capabilities: {
'browserName': 'chrome',
'chromeOptions': {
    'args': ['--no-sandbox', '--test-type=browser'],
    'prefs': {
      'download': {
        'prompt_for_download': false,
        'default_directory': 'C:/Temp'
      }
    }
}
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: conf.baseUrl,
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  ...
```

Comment: Nope! It does not work even with the directConnect set to true!

Comment: what is the version of node, npm and protractor you are using?

Comment: Joes-MacBook-Pro:http jothi$ node --version
v8.1.4